# Distance between 2 points (Lat,Lon) and error Division by zero

Tags: sql, ms-access, distance, trigonometry

I would like to find the distance between 2 points using Lat,Long in microsoft access.
The formula can give the result what I want but when I filter by putting condition, for example <3km or <=5km, there is always error shows 'Division by zero'.

I was trying to use Coalesce cover over Sqr part but still the same error show up
May I know which part of the equation become zero?

```
DIST_Km: Round(((Atn(-(Cos((3.14*(90-[LOC_22AUG2022_1]![Lat]))/180)*Cos((3.14*(90-[LOC_22AUG2022]![Lat]))/180)+Sin((3.14*(90-[LOC_22AUG2022_1]![Lat]))/180)*Sin((3.14*(90-[LOC_22AUG2022]![Lat]))/180)*Cos((3.14*([LOC_22AUG2022_1]![Lon]-[LOC_22AUG2022]![Lon]))/180))/(Sqr(-(Cos((3.14*(90-[LOC_22AUG2022_1]![Lat]))/180)*Cos((3.14*(90-[LOC_22AUG2022]![Lat]))/180)+Sin((3.14*(90-[LOC_22AUG2022_1]![Lat]))/180)*Sin((3.14*(90-[LOC_22AUG2022]![Lat]))/180)*Cos((3.14*([LOC_22AUG2022_1]![Lon]-[LOC_22AUG2022]![Lon]))/180))*(Cos((3.14*(90-[LOC_22AUG2022_1]![Lat]))/180)*Cos((3.14*(90-[LOC_22AUG2022]![Lat]))/180)+Sin((3.14*(90-[LOC_22AUG2022_1]![Lat]))/180)*Sin((3.14*(90-[LOC_22AUG2022]![Lat]))/180)*Cos((3.14*([LOC_22AUG2022_1]![Lon]-[LOC_22AUG2022]![Lon]))/180))+1)))+2*Atn(1))*6371),2)
```

Comment: Access does not support Coalesce function so where are you building this expression?

Comment: If you really want your expression to work, I need sample data and the rest of the SQL statement. Edit your question.

Comment: Or try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676360/distance-using-longitude-and-latitude-excel-vba-to-access-vba.

Comment: Hi, After I tried to look the way by not creating VBA code, seem microsoft access is not have a good choice to work with SQL

I switch to mySQL, and use built-in function "ST_Distance_Sphere". It is very straight forward.